# How to add seconds to an string with ffmpeg timestamp format?

Tags: python, regex, string

If the part in bold of this string are the seconds. 00:00:00:**00**.000

How could I add 10 seconds to all this string formats ?

```
00:00:00:00.000
00:00.000
00.000
```

The result should be:

```
00:00:00:10.000
00:10.000
10.000
```

Comment: You don't have fixed pattern in your input.

Comment: `s/00\./10./g;`

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject anything can be done. We just have to find a way. Look at the answer!

Comment: I don't get why 5 users put this question on hold. It's easy to understand. To those users, read the answer. Obviously he understood it. The question **don't need** to be reworded. And it's a perfect answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with replacement function:

```
>>> import re
>>> strings = [
...     '00:00:00:00.000',
...     '00:00.000',
...     '00.000',
... ]
>>> for s in strings:
...     re.sub(r'\d+(?=\.\d+$)', lambda match: str(int(match.group()) + 10), s)                        
...
'00:00:00:10.000'
'00:10.000'
'10.000'
```

- `re.sub` accept not only the replacement string as the second parameter, but can also accept replacement function as the second parameter.
- The function receive matched object as the parameter. The return value of the function is used as a replacemnt string.
- `\d+(?=\.\d+$)` pattern is used to match last second part (which is followed by `.nnn` decimal part)

Comment: nice but cann you explain what `str(int(match.group()) + 10), s)` does. Please?

Comment: @s_vishnu, `match.group()` returns matched string part. `int(..) + 10` to convert the string into integer, then add 10. After that used `str(..)` to convert integer back to string.

Comment: @s_vishnu, I updated answer (while you were commenting). Reading updated part will also help you understand what that part means. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that come to my mind:

1. Find or write your own converter of string to timestamp format, then increase it by 10s and convert back.
2. Write your own function that takes string, checks in which format it is and adds 10s shifting it to minutes if necessary.